# Add text to leaflet map in rCharts

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, rcharts

I'm using `rCharts` to create a leaflet map in RStudio.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to add text to the resultant map at a specific point ([e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/CrqkR/6/))

I can't see this as a specific feature noted on the rCharts leaflet github page: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/R/Leaflet.R

Any suggestions are most welcome,

Many thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest the [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) package, as it is more actively maintained:

```
library(leaflet)

content <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
  "I am some text"
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content,
    options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

[image]